# How can I get application version from App Store Connect using bash scripts or fastlane action?

Tags: ios, bash, app-store-connect, fastlane

I can read and change `version` and `build` locally using `PlistBuddy` tool (it looks `CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString` fields in `Info.plist` files). Now I use it for auto increase build number of my applications.

But also I want to fetch version number from [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com).
I found similar solution at Fastlane:

- [`app_store_build_number` action](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/app_store_build_number/)
- `Spaceship::Tunes::Application.find(app_identifier)` method from [fastlane sources](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/)

But they works with builds but not with App Store Connect metadata!

It means that if I will create app version eg `1.2.3` but will not upload binary, these solutions will return previous version that has uploaded binaries - eg `1.2.2`.

Is it possible to get application version from App Store Connect metadata?
Does not matter - ready script, url with description or any other.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking approximatively for the same thing. 
This is how I get the last deployed to production version:

```
apple_id = CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig.try_fetch_value(:apple_id)
  app_identifier = CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig.try_fetch_value(:app_identifier)
  Spaceship::Tunes.login(apple_id)

  lastBuild = Spaceship::Tunes::Application.find(app_identifier).versions_history.last.version_string
```

Answer (score 1):

This information is now accessible in Fastlane via lane variables.

```
lane :live_version do
  app_store_build_number()
  
  puts "live-version: #{lane_context[SharedValues::LATEST_VERSION]}"
end
```

Then run `fastlane live_version`.